# Unable to invoke second Lambda from first with enabled VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I am trying to invoke an AWS Lambda function from another one. But after adding VPC with Lambda I receive this error:

> send request failed caused by: Post "https://lambda.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/seconda_lambda/invocations"

Here is the function:

```
_invoke_copier_lambda(map[string]string{
   "parameter1" : "param_val",
})

func _invoke_copier_lambda(params map[string]string) error {
    // Marshal the map into a JSON string.
    bytes__data, err := json.Marshal(params)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    jsonStr := string(bytes__data)
    svci := sLambda.New(session.New())
    input := &sLambda.InvokeInput{
        FunctionName: aws.String(config.CopierLambdaName),
        Payload:      []byte(jsonStr),
    }

    _, err = svci.Invoke(input)
    return err
}
```

What have I missed?

Comment: Is the first Lambda function connected to a VPC? If so, is it connected to a public or a private subnet, and is there a NAT Gateway in the VPC?

Comment: yes, two lambda functions are connected in same VPC public subnet. Also have a NAT Gateway for the VPC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API endpoint for AWS Lambda lives on the Internet. Therefore, invoking a Lambda function requires access to the Internet.

It appears that your Lambda functions are in a public subnet. This means that they do *not* have access to the Internet. To be able to communicate with the Internet an AWS Lambda function must either:

- Be configured to *not* use a VPC, *OR*
- Be configured to connect to a **private subnet** in a VPC, and the VPC has an NAT Gateway or NAT Instance in a public subnet. Also, the Route Table for the private subnet(s) point to the NAT Gateway/NAT Instance.

**Lambda Destinations**

There is actually an alternative way for one Lambda function to trigger another Lambda function by using the [Lambda Destinations](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-aws-lambda-destinations/) feature. When the first Lambda function completes, it can trigger another Lambda function as a Destination. This does *not* require Internet access because it is handled by the AWS Lambda service itself (rather than calling an API). Please note that Destinations is only available if the first function is triggered **asynchronously**.

See:

- [Introducing AWS Lambda Destinations | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-aws-lambda-destinations/)
- [Trek10 | Lambda Destinations: What We Learned the Hard Way](https://www.trek10.com/blog/lambda-destinations-what-we-learned-the-hard-way)